# What is the actual name of a "random key dictionary" structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need a data structure like a dictionary, but I don't care about the keys used. I just want to use the key as a handle, to recognize the item, so I'd like to let the structure choose it.

Example:

```
RandomKeyDict dict;
Key k = dict.insert(foobar);
...
// somewhere else in the code
dict.get(k);
```

How is this structure actually called?

edit: I don't think that `vector` is my guy here, because I also need to remove items from the structure.

Comment: Hash and key are two different things. You care about the key but not about the hash, right?

Comment: No, the key could be 0, 1234, 31415, 42, whatever. I just want to be sure that using the key returned when inserting an object will return the same object.

Comment: Seems like you want a dictionary

Comment: Perhaps an array or list? If you only care about insertion, the array index is a perfectly valid handle to associate with the element.

Comment: If you do not make the key, don't care about its value, and the value of the key is not related to the object being inserted, then `vector` is your data structure. Push the object back into the vector; the next key is the new size of the vector minus one.

Comment: @BlackBear I should have used the word "Dictionnary" from the beginning instead of Hash, right. ;) It stills requires me to provide the Key.

Comment: @NickJohnson Problem is that I often add/remove elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "quasidictionary". See ["An Efficient Quasidictionary", by Torben Hagerup and Rajeev Raman](http://www.cs.le.ac.uk/people/rraman/papers/own/hagerup-raman-swat-2002.ps).

Comment: Can you explain what a quasidictionary is? If that link disappears this answer will be orphaned. Also PostScript files are difficult to read for many people.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! A PDF version here: http://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/math/Data_Structure_And_Algorithms/Algorithm%20Theory%20-%20SWAT%202002%20-%20M.%20Penttonen.pdf

Comment: @JohnKugelman "A quasidictionary is similar to a
dictionary, the difference being that the names identifying data items
are chosen by the data structure rather than by its user." (from the abstract)

Comment: Please put that into your answer (and preferably more than just the one sentence). Answers should be standalone and not depend on links.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation-wise, you can create this yourself using a dictionary as the backend with the frontend generating arbitrary keys. You'll want to guarantee key uniqueness, so I'd suggest something like an incrementing counter rather than random keys which might repeat.

Terminology-wise, you could call the keys **handles**, since they resemble opaque pointers used to lookup objects such as you might find in C or in Win32 programming. Or **tickets**, like from a coat check room or car valet.

Comment: Yes, dictionary + random keys is a solution to implement it, but I was wondering whether there could be algorithms taking benefit of this freedom in the choice of keys, like to balance a tree or something.

Comment: A hash table has O(1) amortized lookups and insertions. Since key ordering doesn't matter, that's pretty much optimal.